# processing strategy of message in spring kafka listener

Tags: spring-kafka

Just wanted to make sure that whether messages are processed in correct way or not. When the message gets received at listener, it will be always processed by a new thread( defined the processor bean as prototype). is this implementation correct ? (i have Considered the listener is not thread safe, so for this reason the prototype scope of bean to process the message has been used)

(Input : TestTopic- 5 partitions - 1 consumer) or (Input : TestTopic- 5 partitions - 5 consumers)

```
public class EventListener {

    @Autowired
    private EventProcessor eventProcessor;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "TestTopic", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
            autoStartup = "true")
    public void onMessage(
            @Payload List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecords, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        eventProcessor.processAndAcknowledgeBatchMessages(consumerRecords, acknowledgment);
    }

}
```

//event processor

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class EventProcessorImpl implements EventProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducerTemplate kafkaProducerTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper localObjectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    public void processAndAcknowledgeBatchMessages(
            List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecords, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        consumerRecords.forEach( consumerRecord -> {
            Event event = localObjectMapper.readValue(consumerRecord.value(), Event.class);
            dao.save(process(event));
        });
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not correct; you should not execute on another thread; it will cause problems with committing offsets and error handling.

Also, making the `EventProcessorImpl` a prototype bean won't help. That just means a new instance is used each time the bean is referenced.

Since it is `@Autowired` it is only referenced once, during initialization. To get a new instance for each request, you would need to call `getBean()` on the application context each time.

It is better to make your code thread-safe.

**EDIT**

There are (at least) a couple of ways to deal with a not thread-safe service defined in prototype scope.

1. Use a ThreadLocal:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So68447863Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68447863Application.class, args);
    }

    private static final ThreadLocal<NotThreadSafeService> SERVICES = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so68447863", topics = "so68447863", concurrency = "5")
    void listen(String in) {
        NotThreadSafeService service = SERVICES.get();
        if (service == null) {
            service = this.context.getBean(NotThreadSafeService.class);
            SERVICES.set(service);
        }
        service.process(in);
    }

    @EventListener
    void removeService(ConsumerStoppedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Consumer stopped; removing TL");
        SERVICES.remove();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so68447863").partitions(10).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    NotThreadSafeService service() {
        return new NotThreadSafeService();
    }

}

class NotThreadSafeService {

    void process(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg + " processed by " + this);
    }

}
```

2. Use a pool of instances.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So68447863Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68447863Application.class, args);
    }

    private static final BlockingQueue<NotThreadSafeService> SERVICES = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so68447863", topics = "so68447863", concurrency = "5")
    void listen(String in) {
        NotThreadSafeService service = SERVICES.poll();
        if (service == null) {
            service = this.context.getBean(NotThreadSafeService.class);
        }
        try {
            service.process(in);
        }
        finally {
            SERVICES.add(service);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so68447863").partitions(10).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    NotThreadSafeService service() {
        return new NotThreadSafeService();
    }

}

class NotThreadSafeService {

    void process(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg + " processed by " + this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary!!  I have a question here.  if we enable the concurrency 5, so 5 more concurrent threads gets started to listen from 5 partitions right? so, in this case the EventprocessorImpl  class which is default scoped with singleton, cause the concurrent issues . What i meant to say is , all 5 threads starts delegating the process logic to same EventProcessorImpl class which leads to unexpected results..right?

Comment: Yes; that is how it works; there is only one instance; you would have to use a `ThreadLocal` to hold an instance (obtained from the application context) for each thread.

Comment: First, do you have any reference implementation on this use case? Second, Do you mean create ThreadLocal<EventProcessorImpl> objects of count equivalent to partition count, so that each concurrent thread will use its respective EventprocessorImpl class?

Comment: No I don’t. You should use `tl.get()` and, if null, get a new prototype instance from the context and `tl.set()`. Or you could use a pool of instances, e.g. in a `BlockingQueue`. But it would be better to make your code thread-safe.

Comment: I get what you say. But how do I get the listener threads(total 5) ? I know we can get the current thread instance within the listener. But this won’t work. First we need to capture all the threads.if  you can provide some sample code , that would help a lot ..

Comment: It's pretty simple. See the edits to the answer. You simply do it dynamically; it is best practice to clear the thread local when the thread terminates.

Comment: There was a bug in my second example - fixed.

Comment: Hi Gary!.. i went for the first approach and  implemented these listener changes at a separate component class . but i am seeing an exception called -"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Container should never call this" and exception stack trace is - "at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler.handle(ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler.java:35)
 at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler.handle(ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler.java:30)
 at"

Comment: Which  version are you using? That problem was fixed a couple of weeks ago but, unfortunately, by mistake, the fix didn't make it into the 2.7.x branch (only 2.8 (pre-release), 2.6, 2.5, 2.4, 2.3. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1855

Comment: i am using spring kafka - 2.3.8

Comment: The fix will be in 2.3.14; I will release it tomorrow. This will be the last release since Boot 2.2.x (which uses this version is out of OSS support). You should consider upgrading to a newer, supported, release. The current version is 2.7.4, used by Boot 2.5.3.

Comment: sorry its my bad.. i am using the spring boot- 2.3.8. so do you mean should i use spring boot 2.5.3 ? or any other version where the fix is available?

Comment: No; 2.7.4 doesn't have the fix, for the reason I mentioned. The fix will be in 2.6.10 and 2.5.15, which I can release tomorrow. 2.6.x can be used with Boot 2.3.x and 2.4.x. https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#overview In the meantime, you can use 2.6.10-SNAPSHOT or 2.5.15.RELEASE from https::/repo.spring.io/snapshot

Comment: Hi Gary!! is the springboot 2.3.8 version released with the mentioned fix?

Comment: No, because I didn’t hear back from you. It will have to be Monday, now.

Comment: Thanks Gary!. i am waiting on that fix . Please add a comment once you are done. i can not go higher versions as per our project req

Comment: Ok. There is a typo in my comment above. You can test with 2.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from the snapshot repo.

Comment: 2.5.15.RELEASE and 2.6.10 are now availble - both can be used with Boot 2.3.x.

Comment: what would be the default kafka version which will be part of boot : 2.3.8 , if we do not mention the kafka version ? I mean this fix should be available all versions of kafka , which should be part of boot:2.3.8. right ?

Comment: No; 2.3.8 pulls in 2.5.11; the current Boot 2.3.x version is 2.3.12, which pulls in spring-kafka 2.5.14.RELEASE; you have to override that version in your pom (or gradle build script) to 2.5.15.RELEASE. Instructions here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.15.RELEASE/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: Hi Gary!!  i did revert  to spring-boot:3.2.8 with default kafka version as i messed up something with kafka:2.6.10. but still i am seeing the issue  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-3-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Error handler threw an exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Container should never call this
 at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler.handle(ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler.java:35)
 at

Comment: You will continue to see that issue unless you override the spring-kafka version to 2.5.15.RELEASE or 2.6.10.

Comment: Gary,  Got a question,  do you mean spring kafka version (mentioned versions) should be explicitly overridden with spring boot 3.2.8 , otherwise we will see this issue ? it seems the current running version (boot:3.2.8 with default kafka) are working in other modules without any issue.

Comment: This is only a bug when using that particular error handler. See the documentation to see how to override the versions. While you are at it, you might as well also upgrade to Spring Boot 2.3.12. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: Gary.. i have tested with all possibilities of  spring boot :3.2.8 with kafka : 2.5.15.RELEASE and  2.6.10. 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.15.RELEASE</version><!--also tested with 2.6.10-->
  </dependency>
Also tested with boot:2.3.12 with default kafka, and also with the above versions. But nothing is working and shows the error - UnsupportedOperationException: Container should never call

Comment: That is not possible. Something is amiss. Edit the question to show your code, configuration, and the complete stack trace.